# Creating LSD-SLAM static library for Android

Tags: android, static-libraries, ros, slam-algorithm

I'm trying to create a LSD-SLAM static library in order to use it on an Android app. You know, the current LSD-SLAM program is for ROS on ubuntu. Does someone know a good tutorial or maybe if someone converted the library to Android already?

Thanks

The open-source project is the following: https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam
and the research is from: http://vision.in.tum.de/research/lsdslam

Comment: In their video the authors run LSD-SLAM on a mobile device (only for visual odometry) https://youtu.be/GnuQzP3gty4?t=22s  I should ask them what library they used.

Comment: They said that 'Android-specific optimizations and AR integration are not part of the open-source release."